# How to use angular directive inside a markdown that is converted via Showdown?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, markdown, angular-ui

I have a markdown directive that loads a markdown file and displays it as HTML:

// detail.html

```
<div markdown link="{{post.file"}}"></div>
```

This works fine, even when I have HTML tags in the markdown files. But I am trying to use AngularUI Bootstrap directives, Tabs in particular, on a markdown page.

Those tabs have content that is specific to each markdown file so for that reason I cannot place a directive outside the markdown file.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. You have to use `$compile` service. Here is the complete code example:

```
angular.module('MyApp')
  .directive('markdown', function($http, $compile) {
    var converter = new Showdown.converter();
    return {
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        attrs.$observe('file', function(file) {
          if (file) {
            $http.get('posts/' + file).success(function(response) {
              var htmlText = converter.makeHtml(response);
              element.html(htmlText);

              $compile(element.contents())(scope);

            });
          }
        });
      }
    }
  });
```